# Data transformation - mask a part of sequence from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need your help.
I would like to: Mask all the letters with "x" before the sequence "-SMS send".

My dataset is:

| Desc | Desired output |
| --- | --- |
| user_m503418 - SMS send | xxxx_x503418 - SMS send |
| cyberx_323 - SMS send | xxxxxx_323 - SMS send |

Thanks :)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

As a begining :

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(LEFT([Desc], CHARINDEX('- SMS send', [Desc]) - 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') + RIGHT([Desc], LEN([Desc]) - CHARINDEX('- SMS send', [Desc]) + 1)
```

Comment: Hello SQLPro, thank you very much for your support.
But.. I've encountered a problem:
when I have another description like : dser - SMS afsendt (without numbers) It doesn't work.

Comment: Read my correction please

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Desc] VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Desc]) VALUES
('user_m503418 - SMS send'),
('cyberx_323 - SMS send'),
('dser - SMS afsendt');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @searchFor VARCHAR(50) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    , @sms VARCHAR(20) = '- SMS';

SELECT *
    , Result = TRANSLATE(LEFT([Desc], pos-1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
            , @searchFor, REPLICATE('x', LEN(@searchFor))) 
        + SUBSTRING([Desc], pos,255)
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT  CHARINDEX(@sms, [Desc])) AS t(pos);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------+-----+-------------------------+
| ID |          Desc           | pos |         Result          |
+----+-------------------------+-----+-------------------------+
|  1 | user_m503418 - SMS send |  14 | xxxx_x503418 - SMS send |
|  2 | cyberx_323 - SMS send   |  12 | xxxxxx_323 - SMS send   |
|  3 | dser - SMS afsendt      |   6 | xxxx - SMS afsendt      |
+----+-------------------------+-----+-------------------------+
```